# Problems streaming UPNP/DLNA from Ubuntu machine

Tags: 11.04, streaming, mediaserver, upnp, dlna

I've set up both mediatomb and minidlna on my ubuntu 10.04 PC.  They both stream media perfectly to my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy) and Google TV (Logitech Revue) using UPNP.
Yet my laptop (Ubuntu 11.04), does not see my PC's services on the network.

### Update

Forgot to mention that, on my laptop, I've tried both **boxee** and **totem**, with the **Coherence plugins**, with no results.

Comment: I'm running the xbmc client on my Natty laptop against mediatomb on my lucid server.  That combinations works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

What software are you using as a client?  Or are you looking for a software recommendation?

If you are after a software recommendation, Ubuntu's default movie player (Totem) can act as a DLNA player if you install the `totem-plugins-extra` package.  Once the package is installed, start the movie player and pick `Plugins...` from the `Edit` menu.  Check the checkbox next to `Coherence DLNA/UPnP Client` and you should be good to go.

Open the movie player's side bar and select Coherence in the drop down menu.  You should now be able to browse the DLNA servers on the local network and start playing movies or songs by double clicking on them.

Comment: Forgot to mention that, on my laptop, I've tried both boxee and totem, with the Coherence plugins, with no results.

Comment: Okay.  In that case, could you try installing the `gupnp-tools` package and see if your media servers show up when you run `gupnp-universal-cp`?  This is a low level tool that shows all the UPnP devices on the network (not just media servers).  Does it show anything?

Comment: I just tried it and nothing shows, yet my Android phone and my Google TV see it fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have another machine available to test with right now.

Comment: LOL!  I just found it.  It was my laptop's own firewall which was blocking it.  When I deactivated it, it started working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

UPnP plugin no longer available in Totem 3.0.1. Looks like package maintainer has removed: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=694507